# Creating a populated dropdownlist with items in the view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to create a dropdownlist that contains a list of items:

```
@Html.DropDownList("displayCount", new SelectList(        
    new[]
    {
        new SelectListItem { Value = "25", Text = "25" },
        new SelectListItem { Value = "50", Text = "50" },
        new SelectListItem { Value = "100", Text = "100" },
    }
));
```

When I look at my dropdownlist, it just has 3 options that say "System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem"

What do I need to do differently here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
@Html.DropDownList("displayCount", new SelectList(        
    new[]
    {
        new SelectListItem { Value = "25", Text = "25" },
        new SelectListItem { Value = "50", Text = "50" },
        new SelectListItem { Value = "100", Text = "100" },
    },
    "Value",
    "Text"
));
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell the SelectList what fields to use:

```
new SelectList(..., "Value", "Text")
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you got `"System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem"` listed in your dropdown is because you didn't specify which attribute of the List Item you want to use for the `Text` and `Value` of the dropdown list. Right now, it is being displayed based on the `.ToString()` of each item in the list, which returns the full name of the `SelectListItem` class

```
@Html.DropDownList("displayCount", new SelectList(        
    new[]
    {
        new SelectListItem { Value = "25", Text = "25" },
        new SelectListItem { Value = "50", Text = "50" },
        new SelectListItem { Value = "100", Text = "100" },
    },
    "Value",
    "Text"
));
```